# Extract content after "=" and before "&", Regex expression in java

Tags: java, regex

guys, I wanna extract the content in a string, the content is before "&" and after the "=", like this example:

```
asdfaf=afl10109&adsfjkl
```

I want to extract "afl10109" out of the string, can anyone teach me how to do this, I am very new to regex expression...

Comment: It would help if you just wrote `foo=bar123&otherfoo` instead of random keystrokes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `replaceAll()` to replace the whole input with just what you want:

```
String target = str.replaceAll(".*=(.*)&.*", "$1");
```

The target is captured in a group (group number 1), which is then referenced in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {
          String input="asdfaf=afl10109&adsfjkl";
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=[^&]*&");
          Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
          while (m.find()) {
              String str = m.group();             
              System.out.println( str.substring(1,str.length()-1));
          }
      }
```

Comment: Thans upog, very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not `regex` but you can also use `split()`

```
String str = "asdfaf=afl10109&adsfjkl";
System.out.println(str.split("=")[1].split("&")[0]);
```

*Output:*

```
afl10109
```

Comment: Thanks, Tarsem, very nice solution by using split function.

Answer (score 1):

Using good old `String#substring()`

```
String str = "foo=bar&baz";
int begin = str.indexOf('=');
if (begin != -1) {
    int end = str.indexOf('&', begin);
    if (end != -1) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(begin+1, end)); // bar
    }
}
```